# Polymer 1.0: how to correctly bind to (inject / override) a function of a dom-module

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a Polymer element of which the public API should allow to bind to a function which the user can define, i.e. it should allow to pass in a function implementation. I have tried quite a few approaches but only 1 worked. Now I'm wondering if this is the proper / correct way or not.

To rephrase: what is the proper way to bind a function as part of a `dom-module`'s public API? The only way I have this achieved somewhat is as follows:

```
    <dom-module id="channel-search">

    <template>
        <remote-dropdown
          id="dropdown"
          label-text="Type channel name" 
          url='{{_findRecordUrl}}' 
          url-transformer='{{urlTransformer}}' 
          result-to-list-transformer='{{resultToListTransformer}}' 
          class="layout horizontal" 
          style='width: 100%'>
        </remote-dropdown>
    </template>

    </dom-module>

    <script>
   (function() {
    Polymer({
      is: 'channel-search',

      properties: {
        _findRecordUrl: {
          type: String,
          value: 'http://127.0.0.1:9292/epics-boot-info.psi.ch/find-channel.aspx'
        }
      },

      /*
        * Here in the attached function, I define the methods which will then be bound to
        * the respective properties of the remote-dropdown element
        */
      attached: function() {

        this.urlTransformer = function(baseUrl, currentInput) {
          return baseUrl + '/' + currentInput;
        };

        this.resultToListTransformer = function(findRecordList) {
          var responseList = findRecordList.map(function(res) {
            return res.Channel;
          });
          return responseList;
        };

      }

    });
  })();
</script>
```

So, I needed to define the functions in the `attached` callback in order for them to be properly bound to the `remote-dropdown` element's public API.

I hoped it would be a bit clearer / easier, maybe like so:

```
<script>
   (function() {
    Polymer({
      is: 'channel-search',

      properties: {
        _findRecordUrl: {
          type: String,
          value: 'http://127.0.0.1:9292/find-channel.aspx'
        }
      },

      urlTransformer: function(baseUrl, currentInput) {
          return baseUrl + '/' + currentInput;
      };

      resultToListTransformer: function(findRecordList) {
          var responseList = findRecordList.map(function(res) {
            return res.Channel;
          });
          return responseList;
      };

    });
  })();
</script>
```

i.e. simply define the function implementation as part of the element's definition and then bind those to the embedded `remote-dropdown` element. However, that never seemed to work as I thought it would (also not variations thereof) - surely also because of my limited knowledge of Polymer/Javascript internals.

My question is: is the solution using the `attached` callback the proper way to achieve what I am trying to do? If not, what would be the correct way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do that using [computed properties](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#computed-properties) or [computed bindings](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#annotated-computed). Your first answer looks like a variation of the latter.

Comment: I've looked at computed properties/bindings before but they seem unsuitable to my needs because in order for them to be evaluated, one needs to know the argument values of the computed function to be called when the element is stamped / created.
What I am looking for is actually simpler. I just want to pass in the implementation of a function which then subsequently gets called from inside the the `remote-dropdown` element.